# difference method open file in python

Tags: python

This is first time I post question and thank you in advance for answer.

Is there any different with both method to open file in Python?

1.

```
file_stream = open('jsonfile.json')
ujson.load(file_stream)
```

2.

```
with open('jsonfile.json') as file_stream:
    ujson.load(file_stream)
```

Comment: Your subject says "error when loading file stream with ujson". But your question is about the difference between using a `with` statement and an assignment statement with an `open` call. If you have a question about an error, ask about that error, not about something unrelated to it.

Comment: Thanks for point out. Correct title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the second method the file will be automatically closed at the end of the with block.

In the first method that doesn't happen and you must manually call `file_stream.close()` to ensure the file is closed.

See also the [documentation regarding input and output](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the equivalent without `with` wouldn't just be manually calling `close`, but using a `try`/`finally` block with the `close` in it, so that even if the `ujson.load` raises an exception the file still gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference there is that your second method is automatically closing the file. The first method would require an additional line to close the file.